# Simplest Proof of Euclid's Formula for Primitive Triples?

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, pythagorean-triples

A right triangle with side lengths $a,b,c$ where $c$ is the hypotenuse and using integers $m, n $ where $ m > n$, we can find Euclid's Formula.

First, given a right triangle with an hypotenuse $\sqrt{c}$ we can set its side lengths to be m and n, giving $c = m^2 + n^2$. Next, this works for all primitives, which can be proven given the greatest side length is always an odd number telling us that when m and n are even and odd, they will at minimum work for all primitives.

Using this we now can find the integer values of a and b.

$(m^2 + n^2)^2 = c^2$

$m^4 + 2m^2n^2 + n^4 = c^2$

$(m - n)^2 + (2mn)^2 = c^2$

Which results in Euclid's formula:

$(2mn, m^2 - n^2, m^2 + n^2)$

Is this proof valid?

Comment: It looks like you didn't prove these are *all* the triples, only that they are each a triple.

Comment: the wikipedia-article should contain a proof that those are in fact all the primitive triples , where $m$ and $n$ are coprime and have different parity.

Comment: I tried proving it for primitive triples,

Comment: Why would there be a right-angled triangle with hypotenuse $\sqrt{c}$ and integer legs?

Comment: @user10354138 Here is an example:  $2^2 + 3^2 = c\implies  \sqrt{c} = \sqrt{13}$

Comment: You don't know $c$ is a sum of two squares yet.  You only know $c^2$ is a sum of two squares.  It is on you to prove that in all such cases $c$ is indeed a sum of two squares.

Comment: Given c is an odd integer, using Pythagorean theorem we have $c = side length^2 + side length^2$ where the side lengths can be m  and n as long as they are odd and even.

Comment: Why you call this Euclid's Formula?

Comment: Your claim is really - if there exist an integer relation between the sides than this is the triplet structure.

Comment: You have to multiply each term with $k\in\mathbb{N}$ to generate every PT.

Comment: Not every odd integer is the sum of two squares of integers. In other words, not for every odd $c$, there are integers $m,n$ with $c=m^2+n^2$